# Attempt to send email through Xamarin App...Works ok with UWP but fails with Andoid - Specified method is not supported. Code attached

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

The code works fine in UWP but fails in Android. Receive error "Specified method is not supported." in my Try...Catch. According to @JamesMontemagno, this code should work. Refer to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ-Yw9CRxAY for more specifics of the application. The code is presented below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SendEmail.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Email Sample" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Button x:Name="SendEmail" Text="Send" Clicked="SendEmail_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SendEmail
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void SendEmail_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string body = "Test bowling message";
            string[] to = { "user@outlook.com"};
            //EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment(attach); 
            
            var message = new EmailMessage("Bowlers Scheduled for Week", body, to);
            //message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            try
            {
                await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //bool result = await DisplayAlert(ex.ToString(), "Send Email", "Yes", "No");
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the stack trace show?

Comment: at Xamarin.Essentials.Email.ComposeAsync (Xamarin.Essentials.EmailMessage message) [0x00007] in D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\Email\Email.shared.cs:19 
  at SendEmail.MainPage.SendEmail_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00053] in D:\Projects\Temp\SendEmail\SendEmail\SendEmail\MainPage.xaml.cs:29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code, and it worked well on my side. Here are the issues maybe you met.

First, if your project's Target Android version is set to Android 11 (R API 30) you must update your Android Manifest with queries that are used with the new [package visibility requirements](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility).

Please add the following inside of the manifest node:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Second, Email.ComposeAsync will returns `FeatureNotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'` if no email client app is available on the device to send an email. You can install the Gmail application on the phone and when you click the button it will open the Gmail and send the email.

Comment: Bingo, your manifest query code worked. I am very grateful. Thank you very much.